# Can I answer "No to All" when doing a copy in Windows?

Tags: windows, file-management, rsync, merge

When copying/merging large directory structures under Windows, is it possible to do something like "Yes to all" but in reverse so that all existing files are *not* overwritten?

There is a similar functionality when using tools like `rsync`, but that is not a native process on Windows.

Comment: just rsync from local machine to local machine?  Whats wrong with a non-native process?

Comment: @conspiritech - can't rely on being able to install rsync everywhere :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Vista and Windows 7, there's an option on the Copy/Don't Copy dialog to *Do this for the next N conflicts*. And here's another site ([How to Say ‘No to All’ During File Copy Operations in Windows](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/no-to-all-in-windows-file-copy/6920/)) that mentions the option to `shift+click` the *No* option in the GUI, with screen shots.

Answer (score 2):

You can press "Shift" key and then click on the "No" button to enable "No to All" choice according to this [article](http://www.askvg.com/did-you-know-collection-of-some-simple-and-easy-to-use-tips-and-tricks-for-windows-explorer/)  (which has a number of other useful tips).

Answer (score 1):

This is called `no clobber` in unix, I haven't found a way to do it in the command line for windows, but if you're using a GUI, hold `SHIFT` when you click no, http://www.imaginaryplanet.net/weblogs/idiotprogrammer/2005/06/copy-overwrite-no-to-all/

for command line

> Make the destination files read-only, then use /Y in the copy command?
>   Then you could un-set the read only flag afterward, if necessary.
>   http://whrl.pl/RTc36